# move time series (drop all values below a certain threshold)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following data.frame:

```
A <- c(10,20,30,90,180,400)
B <- c(5, 25, 50, 401, 490, 500)
C <- c(200, 300, 480, 890, 1100, 1200)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
df
```

Which looks like this:

```
    A   B    C
1  10   5  200
2  20  25  300
3  30  50  480
4  90 401  890
5 180 490 1100
6 400 500 1200
```

Now, I'd like to move the time series A, B and C so that the first value is above a certain treshold (e.g. 400). So the result should look like this:

```
     A    B    C
1  400  401  480
2   NA  490  890
3   NA  500 1100
4   NA   NA 1200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over column and filter values which are above threshold. We can then use `cbind.fill` from `rowr` to combine them

```
setNames(do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(sapply(df, function(x) 
                 x[x >= 400]), fill = NA)), names(df))

#    A   B    C
#1 400 401  480
#2  NA 490  890
#3  NA 500 1100
#4  NA  NA 1200
```

---

A `tidyverse` option is :

```
library(tidyverse)

map(df, ~.x[.x >= 400]) %>%
    enframe() %>%
    unnest(value) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider() %>%
    select(-row)
```